# How to take comma seperated input from Textarea as arrays to draw a Bar Graph using <canvas> in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, canvas, multidimensional-array, textarea

I have made Bar Graph using Canvas tag that take input values from text fields and displays the graph accordingly. Code provided...

Now, I need to convert the textbox inputs to a single textarea input which takes input as:

Values: 20,130,70;50,140,80;20,180,50;120,10,20

and converts to an array after taking the "No. Of Bars:"(3 in above eg.) and "No. Of Times:"(4) as input in textboxes.

Also, I would then need to include a function that calculates the space needed for drawing these bars and adjusts their width and space between them accordingly by some factor...

Can anybody help me with any/all of these functions..??

```
<HTML>
<Head>
<Title>Vertical Bar Graph</Title>
<script language = "text/javascript" type="text/javascript">
var canvas;
var context;
var _x = 0;
var _y = 0;
var _z = 0;
var _a = 0;
var _b = 0;
var _c = 0;


function draw(newx,newy,newz,newa,newb,newc) {
newx = _x;
newy = _y;  
newz = _z;
newa = _a;
newb = _b;  
newc = _c;
context.fillStyle="#AA11FF";    
context.fillRect(60,270,25,-newx);
context.fillRect(190,270,25,-newy);
context.fillRect(315,270,25,-newz);
context.fillStyle="#AAEE00";
context.fillRect(85,270,25,-newa);
context.fillRect(215,270,25,-newb);
context.fillRect(340,270,25,-newc);
}
function sendVal(form) { 
_x = form.xx.value;
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
draw(_x);

_y = form.yy.value;
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
draw(_y);
_z = form.zz.value;
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
draw(_z);
_a = form.aa.value;
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
draw(_a);
_b = form.bb.value;
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
draw(_b);
_c = form.cc.value;
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
draw(_c);
context.strokeStyle="#000000";
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(24,5);
context.lineTo(24,270);
context.lineTo(450,270);
context.stroke();
}
window.onload = function() {
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.strokeStyle="#000000";
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(24,5);
context.lineTo(24,271);
context.lineTo(480,271);
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle="#AA11FF";
context.fillRect(60,270,25,-220);
context.fillRect(190,270,25,-150);
context.fillRect(315,270,25,-55);
context.fillStyle="#AAEE00";
context.fillRect(85,270,25,-80);
context.fillRect(215,270,25,-120);
context.fillRect(340,270,25,-175);
};
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#6699FF">
<center>
<U><H2>Vertical Bar Graph</H2></U>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<P>
<FORM NAME="SENDX" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
Enter X: <INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="xx">
Enter Y: <INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="yy">
Enter Z: <INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="zz"><P>
Enter A: <INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="aa">
Enter B: <INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="bb">
Enter C: <INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="cc"><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Enter Co-ordinates" onClick="sendVal(this.form)">
</FORM>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wondering, why aren't you taking advantage of any existing charting library, such as highcharts?

Comment: @MasterAM Although it's a nice way of creating graphs/charts, I needed a more user-driven and 'pure' form of chart...